# what do Present Perfect and due soon mean together?

Tags: grammar

I read this sentence:

- *i didn't get as much for those photos as i hoped, and we have got the mortgage due soon.*

I can't understand what is passing **due soon** here?
The offer talks about a past event(we got a mortgage ) but as i understand it, due soon passes the value of *soon*, *about to*, i.e. something closer to the future event .So what is it for in this sentence?
I would be happy to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Have got* looks like a present perfect (and historically was one) but in modern English, it is very often present - it is just a less formal form of *have*.

So the second clause means exactly the same as *we have the mortgage due soon*. This means much the same as *the mortgage is due soon*, but explicitly linking this to us.

In some contexts *We have got the mortgage* can be present perfect: "We've been waiting for our solicitor to send the right papers, but we've finally got the mortgage!" But that meaning doesn't make sense here - partly because of the *due soon*. (I believe this use is less common in US English than British English, because US English prefers *gotten* as the pp of *get*).

Comment: tnanks for your help !